# Average related question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

Can some one please let me know how to solve this problem for my son's home work assignment which i am not able to understand.

after taking 3 quizzes, your average is 72 out of 100. What must your average be on the  next five quizzes to increase your average to 77.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  If your average on 3 is 72, you have scored 216 so far.  To average 77 on 8 quizzes, you need how many points?  How many more points do you need?  The average over 5 quizzes then needs to be ???

Comment: Thanks much for the reply. Is the answer 80 right?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 80.

Suppose $(x_1+x_2+x_3)/3=72$, and $(x_4+x_5+x_6+x_7+x_8)/5=A$.

You want $(\{x_1+x_2+x_3\}+\{x_4+x_5+x_6+x_7+x_8\})/8=77$.

This means $(\{3\cdot72\} + \{5\cdot A\})/8 =77$. Solve to get $A=80$.